# Auto resizing the height of TableViewCell to fit the UIImageVIew in iOS 6

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimage

I have uiimageview property to display image in my table view and would like to let one specific table view cell to change its height according to the height of the image in the uiimageview. Below is what I did. Not really sure why the height of the tableview cell didn't change... :(

`@interface BoatViewController () <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>`

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *boatImageView;

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        return self.boatImageView.image.size.height;
    }else{
        return 44;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try reloading the table view data when everything has finished loading. It may be that when that method was called, iOS hadn't finished calculating the final size of the frame.

In your viedDidAppear method add the call to reload the tableview. See if it helps at all.

Comment: So I added [self.tableview reloadData], but it didn't help. Not sure if this was the issue as well. I loaded the image into uiimageview in viewDidLoad, and the tableviewcell didn't set the height properly too...

Comment: Is the image you're loading a remote image, or is it stored on the device? If it's on the device then try was @Siba suggested. That should hopefully sort it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code hope it help.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {

    CGSize size = image.size; // Assign the image what you want to display.

  //  self.boatImageView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);

    return size.height;

    }else{
        return 44;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, What's the different between `self.boatImageView.image.size.height` and `CGSize size = image.size`.? I thought both would give CGFloat of the size of uiimmage.image.

Comment: Hi in your case you are showing the image in Imageview and then You are Checking the size. Do exactly opposite. First check the size of image and Then put that image into imageview.  

I can explain you better if yiou can show how you are getting the image (from local or remote)

Comment: Aha, I see what you mean. So, what I have been doing was actually trying to use the height of the uiimageview instead of the size from the image itself. This explains it. I shall give it a try tomorrow and let you know. Thanks! :)